# App not working when tested with AS Emulator with certain network types

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I've encountered a problem today when testing my Android app with different emulator settings.

Upon clicking a button a certain amount of data (~161kb) is fetched from an online XML-Document.

Up to now I tested the app with full internet speed and faced no problems when fetching the required data. Same for LTE. However when testing with **HSDPA and lower mobile radio standards** the data wont get loaded.

[image]

The data is fetched from an async background task and the fact that it works with LTE makes me believe the code is doing what it should. Furthemore the amount of data is marginal with ~160kb.

My question: Could this problem be caused by the emulator? If so, how could i resolve it?